# Regex for Capturing Text Between 'word1' and 'word2' with Specific Conditions

Tags: regex

need some help with regex.

I need to capture text, that starts has 'word1' followed by any text in the next n line(for example 6), followed by 'word2' and doesn't contain ';'(semicolon) before 'word2'.
Also, it should stop after reaching the first match.

here is regex that I'm trying:

```
word1.*(?:\R.*){0,5}(?!.*;$).*word2
```

https://regex101.com/r/bZMOFF/2

for example:
1)

```
any random text word1 any random text
any random text any random text
any random text any random text
any random text any random text word2
any random text any random text;
```

2)at this example it should select only up to first word2

```
any random text word1 any random text
any random word2 text any random text word2
any random text any random text
any random text word2 any random text
any random text any random text word2 any random text;
```

3)here it should find anyting

```
any random text word1 any random text
any random text any random text
any random text any random text
any random text any random text
any random text any random text any random text;

any random text any random text word2
```

4)and this one should match also

```
any random text word1 any random text
any random text any random text
any random text any random text
any random text any random text
any random text word2 any random text;
```

issues:

- At scenario 2 - selects everything up to last 'word2'
- At scenario 3 - it should not match, but it matches
- At scenario 4 - does not select 'word2' because semicolon is in the same line

Comment: yes, second approach is what I needed! thank you!

Comment: Welcome...Let me add it as answer then

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that need to be tweaked in your regex to match all your scenarios:

```
word1[^;\n]*(?:\R[^;\n]*?){0,5}word2
      ^^^^        ^^^^
```

**Explanation of above regex:**

- ***`word1`*** - Literally matches `word1`.
- ***`(?: ... ){0,5}`*** - non-capturing group which is repeated 0 to 6 times.

  - ***`\R`*** - matches any Unicode newline sequence.
  - ***`[^;\n]*?`*** - matches any character that is NOT a semicolon (`;`) or a `\n` character 0 or more times but as few times as possible(lazily).
- ***`word2`*** - Literally matches `word2`.

  [image: regex-explanation]

*[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/WwKZ32/9)*

---

###### Edit(h/t *[bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)*)

In my previous response, I also needed to add `\n` character in my negated character class to provide match for only a max of 6(as per the question) lines.<sup>*[fail-case](https://regex101.com/r/O2Be4V/1)*</sup>

Comment: Reads like you need to [add newline `\n` to your negated class](https://regex101.com/r/gaEoN4/1) for max 6 lines, else it can match something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/O2Be4V/1) (arbitrary amount of lines, as long as no semicolon is matched).

Comment: Updated regex at example(added semicolon to scenario 2 and 4) it should not match them, because semicolon is between word1 and word2, but it matches.
https://regex101.com/r/bZMOFF/3